Привет всем.Почему после рендеринга анимации в Blender, у меня появляются артефакты в виде полос,окантовка?
Сразу говорю,что настройки рендера писать не буду,так как они на 101 % правильные, а вот настройки выхода,может быть нет.Сначала на выход я отрендерил на 8бит в пнг.И все прекрасно.Потом все это из пнг сделал в видос через блендер и как раз появляются вот такие вот полосы.Потом попробовал сразу в видос и все так же.Потом решил пнг в 16 бит и уже в видос и все так же.Но в 16 бит смысла нет, у меня монитор на 8 бит.Оно так сжимает или что.Как решить проблему?
